# File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 879, in _find_spec

Tags: python

I got error message like below. The message has more length but I am just showing the beginning of the error. I have no clue on this. Could anyone help? I will show the rest of error message if needed.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 879, in _find_spec
AttributeError: '_SixMetaPathImporter' object has no attribute 'find_spec'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

my actual code is below.

```
import requests
import csv
import datetime 
import os

#  get USDJPY info.
response = requests.get("https://www.gaitameonline.com/rateaj/getrate")
data = response.json()
x = (data["quotes"][20])

#get date and time
d  =    datetime.datetime.today()
date = [0 for I in range(1)]
date[0] = d.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

#write data in csv
with open('csvfile.csv','a') as f:
w = csv.writer(f)
w.writerow(date)
w.writerow(x.values())
```

Comment: Will you please explain it ?

Comment: thanks I added my code in my question. I am trying to get fx data and save it in csv. a part of this code worked a few days ago. But it started not working suddenly since 3 days ago.